# ItemTemplate for UserControls in ItemsControl - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

My task is to implement a MDI-like interface in our WPF app.

I have created this simple class as a base for all the views:

```
public class BaseView : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        private ViewType _type = ViewType.Null;
        private string _tabTitle = string.Empty;
        private bool _isSelected = false;

        public ViewType Type { get => _type; set { _type = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public string TabTitle { get => _tabTitle; set { _tabTitle = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public bool IsSelected { get => _isSelected; set { _isSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
}
```

Next, I created few test Views. All of them start like this:
`<local:BaseView...`

In main window, there are two controls: ItemsControl (for displaying the list of opened views), and ContentControl (for displaying the selected view.)

I store all the opened views in a ObservableCollection: `ObservableCollection<BaseView>...`.
I wanted to display them as a list, so I created ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="mainItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Padding="2" Margin="2" Tag="{Binding Type}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabTitle}" Foreground="White"/>
                        </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

When I set the ItemsControl's source (`mainItemsControl.ItemsSource = openedViews;`) and started the application, ItemsControl displayed the content of each View instead of the ItemTemplate (Border with the TextBlock). What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can datatemplate ui. They are dependency objects. Some people use DO as viewmodels.  But you could instead move those properties into a base viewmodel. Work viewmodel first. Mvvm is the way pretty much everyone does commercial apps with xaml. You should learn mvvm.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, then the openedViews collection consists of BaseView.
If so, then BaseView is a UIElement.
But Data Templates are used to render non UIElements.
If the Content receives a UIElement, then it is rendered directly as is.

**One possible variant solution.**
You need to remove the INotifyPropertyChanged interface from BaseView.
Create a data source for your BaseView with an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.
In BaseView create DependencyProperty for this source.

Create a simple, helper container for the openedViews collection.
Something like this (pseudo code):

```cs
public class SomeContainer 
{
    public BaseDataSource DataSource 
    {
        get => _dataSource;
        set
        {
            _dataSource = null;
            if(View is not null)
            {
                View.DataSource = DataSource;
            }            
        }
    }
    public BaseView View
    {
        get => _view;
        set
        {
            _view = value;
            if(_view is not null)
            {
                _view.DataSource = DataSource;
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So to display the list, I have to create a new class which is not UIElement?

Comment: No. You don't have to.

Comment: @brt99 , I supplemented the answer with one variant of the solutions.